Subdivision Modifier and smooth by angle not creating smooth surfaces
OK Sooo i m not an expert in modeling so the problem is i was following a written tutorial ( no graphics just 2-3 images ) and after everything is done i applied Subdiv Surface Modifier Level 2 and also shade smooth by angle, it came out decent and i am satisfied with the results but the front part of the Model is Just making the whole experience terrible and waste.
I know there are not many loops on that region ( as you can see in the photos) but inserting Edge Loops are changing the shape ( by changing the shape i mean the model look sharp hard surface model ) of "The Front " part of the model completely and i want it smooth. so is there any other way to make just the front part look smooth without adding level 3 of subdivision surface modifier geometry or extra edge loops on whole model.
Thank You in Advance
For Better understanding i have attached the project file, its on polycount website, because i couldn't find any way to upload the project file. so below is the link.
****************File Link - File here, change format from .docx to .blend after downloading
As you can see in the photo below the main issue i have is this area which is shown through the green line. After applying subdivision surface modifier and shade smooth the 3d model still has these harsh edges. Everything else is fine its just this small area.

in this photo - subdivision modifier level 3 is applied, which was the desired result i wanted/ needed but not with extra geometry, of course level 3 added extra geometry Which doesn't seem right to do just for this small area. i am getting good decent results on level 2 so level 3 is just overkill, So if there is a way that I can apply it to the front of this 3D model to somehow get a level 3 result, whether it's adding an extra edge to this area (not the loops to the whole model) or a modifier or some other method.

in this one i thought of adding some extra edges this way.
not the whole loop because adding the loops changes the shape of whole model. visual representation below. i would have done that but the manual work for this issues outweighs the benefits of adding loops.

Just 2 extra reference


**********UPDATE -
i thought of using another primitive for this as you can see below, just experimenting. just checking if this would work. in this - the smoothness on level 2 subdivision modifier is what i wanted. I was hoping to get some smoothness like the "bar on level 2" on the front area of the "jet ski". i had more photos but limitations. i hope you get the idea.



Please don't add "please help" to your posts, let alone the title. You're already making a post on a dedicated help site, and anyone willing to help and reading your question is already trying to help you, so asking again just feels overdramatic.

Oh, well, I didn't want to sound overly dramatic. Thanks for correcting that.

Also don't put text in images, put it above/below them, so it's easier to read and is indexed by search engine.

People usually scroll through text but graphics are attention grabbers. That's the factual reason behind it. I have used tht method in the past and what the results would have been is a different matter altogether. anywy thnks fr cmntng

I mentioned the issue in the form of text in first para, the images are just reference. text on photos are just "in case". I'll edit it anyway, let's see if I find something

I scrolled through the images and didn't read the text because I don't work at pharmacy to decipher handwriting :D

Haha, dude, there is no need to read text from the images, you said you are text reader, and the issue is just first few lines. the text on images are for " Just in case if sm1 ignores the text", well as i said i had experiences

and that why i specially used PS to add text Before you wrote your comment, I added the text properly in PS. The earlier text was written with a mouse and not a pen tablet, otherwise it would have been different story. ;)

You can select edges on your mesh in edit mode and set the Crease strength, Edge -> Edge Crease (Shift E). Drag to your desired hardness. Here's an example with a few different crease strengths on various edges:


thank you, tried your way, just now but still looks like the first image, how can i upload the file here ?

added a link to the file. uploaded on "polycount Website"
